# Check existance of element and assign to variable in one line

Tags: javascript

Can the following check and assignment be written with one line?

```
const panel = this.element.querySelector(".c-global-search__panel");
this.panel = (panel instanceof HTMLElement) ? panel : null;
```

Something like:

```
this.panel = (variable = querySelection and condition) ? assignment : fallback;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple `||` (or), as the return value of `querySelector` is `HTMLElement | null`. `HTMLElement` is truth thus it will be returned, if it is null, fallback is used.

```
this.panel = this.element.querySelector(".c-global-search__panel") || fallback;
```

---

There is also null coalescing operator. This is new and not yet supported by browser (TS and Babel only), but it is better as it does treat false and 0 as valid value too. But in this case it is not needed.

```
this.panel = this.element.querySelector(".c-global-search__panel") ?? fallback;
```

But a side note... The engine will do this optimization anyway, there is no real need to do it. Rather than one-liners focus on readability.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the second line. [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) already returns `null` if no element is found.

```
this.panel = this.element.querySelector(".c-global-search__panel");
```

Your second line setting the value to `null` is redundant.